# Can't run SqlConnection, Win CE 6.0

Tags: mysql, .net

I release my program from Microsoft Visual Studio 2008. 
And it works. But when trying connect to a MySql Database Server I receive the error:

> Error TRF.EXE SqlException
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, TdsParserState state)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(String host,
>   SqlInternalConnection connHandler, Int32 timeout)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConn ection..ctor(SqlConnection
>   connection, Hashtable connectionOptions)      at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection. Open()   at
>   TL.User.set_Password(String value)    at
>   TRF.LoginForm.textBoxPassword_Key Down(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32
>   IParam)   at System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternatWnProc (WM wm,
>   Int32 wParam, Int32 IParam)   at
>   Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterModalDialog(IntPtr hwnModal)     at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ShowDialog()     at TRF.MainForm.login()     at
>   TRF.MainForm.buttonShip_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)     at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)     at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)      at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32
>   IParam)   at System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternatWnProc (WM wm,
>   Int32 wParam, Int32 IParam)   at
>   Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop(IntPtr hwnMain)     at
>   System.Windows.Forms.aplication.Run(Form fm)      at TRF.Program.Main()

Comment: have you used mysql dll ?

Comment: What ups with _more details more details_? provide your mysql code as well so users can help with a solution

Comment: @utility yes i do. Told you, this problem correctly works on other devises.

Comment: are you connecting to any remote online server via application ?

Comment: @utility i using [link](http://automation.bartec.de/DataRoot/mobile/MC9090ex/manuals/motorola/E_Radio_Card_Wireless_Fusion_User_Guide_Version_2.55.pdf) this program for connect to WiFi. Create new profile, it seems everything is working properly, but IPv4 Renewing every 5 second. Mb this my problem? On other devises i using same properties.

Comment: dear @Roman just one question..is database online server ?

Comment: @utility no, this server is my local computer. I will try to come closer to wifi router, and check properties on other devices.

Comment: yes just give an attempt also it would be helpful if you post your query as well

Comment: @utility my other devices have Win CE 5.0 . This Win CE 6.0 , mb this my problem?